# Type modifiers alternative syntax

Tags: c++

In a C++ header file I found this line:

```
_showroot = char(val)
```

(val is an int variable)

and later:

```
return(int(_showroot))
```

(inside a function of type int)

The header is part of the FLTK toolkit.
What does that syntax mean? It seems to be a type casting, but shouldn't it use the syntax "(char)val" instead of "char(val)"? Are the two equivalent, or is there a difference?

Comment: It's equivalent: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: They're [equivalent ways](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) of doing the same C-style cast. One difference is that you can do `(unsigned int)val` but not `unsigned int(val)` because of how tokens with spaces are handled.

Comment: It's a **function-style cast**.